# How do I run two docker stacks from different git branches

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My project has a handful of containers.  They all build perfectly with docker compose.  Sometimes it would be useful to bring up another stack alongside main but from a different branch (without modifying the resources used by main).   I was hoping for some sort of workflow like, building, composing, starting, stopping, removing(containers, images, networks, volumes) based on some sort of tagging, prefixing, or project naming.

I've looked at image tags and project names, but they seem like only partial solutions.

Or am I thinking about this wrong?
What is best practice here?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You can use the `docker-compose -p` option or `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable to set an alternate name that will let you run two copies of the same Compose project in parallel.  Note that the two copies of the service can't publish the same `ports:`, and if you override generated names like `container_name:` then there can be conflicts.